# Can I add an ID to the divs in this Wordpress query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this PHP snippet to wrap every 12 Wordpress posts in a div.

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    echo '<div class="row content-block">';
    if ( $project->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $project->have_posts() ) : $project->the_post();
        get_template_part('project', 'content');
    if($i % 12 == 0) {echo '</div><div class="row content-block">';}
    $i++; endwhile; endif;
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

Is there any way that I can apply unique ID's to the `row content-block` divs? for example `block-1`, `block-2`, etc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes (edited):

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    $id = 2;
    echo '<div class="row content-block" id="block-1">';
    if ( $project->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $project->have_posts() ) : $project->the_post();
        get_template_part('project', 'content');
    if($i % 12 == 0) {echo '</div><div class="row content-block" id="block-' .$id .'">'; $id++;}
    $i++; endwhile; endif;
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: That's great. Is there any way that I can make the ID a consecutive number? Ie; `block-1`, `block-2`, 'block-3`, etc? It's not essential, the current method works fine, it'd just be a bit clearer for my client

Comment: it is ;)
because $i increases each time it goes through the loop!

Comment: It's currently showing as `block-1` and `block-13` (When I have 15 posts showing)...

Comment: Ohhhh I see.. I misunderstood the code sorry (I'm not used to this style) ;)
I edited my post